# Invalid date format when trying to fetch data from firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dayjs

I have a component in which I am trying to fetch the values of sensors based on the time, I was able to get the sensors based on the regular date format, however I have another option where I want it so that the user can get the data based on the month instead of a particular date, However I am not able to do so.

This is my component and functions :

```
const History = (props) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const sensorId = params.sensorId;
  const facilityId = params.facilityId;
  const [zeroFilter, setZeroFilter] = React.useState(true);
  const [history, setHistory] = React.useState([]);
  const displayHistory = history.filter((x) =>
    zeroFilter ? x.value !== 0 : true
  );
  const [date, setDate] = React.useState(null);
  const [month, setMonth] = React.useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const language = props.language;


  const download = () => {
    let csvString = "Value,Date\n";
    let csvStringMonth = "Value,Month\n"



    csvString += displayHistory
      .map(
        (x) =>
          `${x.value},${moment(x.createdAt.seconds * 1000).format(
            "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
          )}`
      )
      .join("\n");

    const file_name = `${facilityId}_${sensorId}.csv`;

    csvStringMonth += displayHistory.map(
      (x) =>
        `${x.value},${moment(x.createdAt.seconds * 1000).format(
          "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
        )}`
    )
      .join("\n");
    //CSVのバイナリデータを作る
    let blob = new Blob([csvString], { type: "text/csv" });
    let uri = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // //リンクタグを作る
    let link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = file_name;
    link.href = uri;

    // //作ったリンクタグをクリックさせる
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();

    // //クリックしたら即リンクタグを消す
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  };
  const changeDate = (newDate) => {
    setDate(newDate);
    getData(newDate);
  };
  const changeMonth = (newMonth) => {
    setMonth(newMonth);
    getDataMonth(newMonth);
  };
  const resetDate = () => {
    setDate(null);
    setMonth(null)
    getData();
    getDataMonth();
  };


  **const getDataMonth = (targetMonth) => {
    setLoading(true);

    // Calculate start and end dates for the selected month
    const startOfMonth = dayjs(targetMonth).startOf("month");
    const endOfMonth = dayjs(targetMonth).endOf("month");

    const q = query(
      collection(db, ENV, VERSION, "facilities", facilityId, "sensorHistory"),
      orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
      where("deviceId", "==", sensorId),
      where("dataType", "==", "data"),
      where("createdAt", ">=", startOfMonth.toDate()),
      where("createdAt", "<=", endOfMonth.toDate())
    );

    getDocs(q)
      .then((querysnapshot) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setHistory(
          querysnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
          })
        );
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        alert("Error fetching data!");
        setLoading(false);
        console.error(e);
      });
  };
**
  const getData = (targetDate) => {
    setLoading(true);
    let q;
    if (targetDate) {
      const start = targetDate.startOf("day").toDate();
      const end = targetDate.add(1, "d").startOf("day").toDate();
      q = query(collection(db, ENV, VERSION, "facilities", facilityId, "sensorHistory"),
        orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
        where("deviceId", "==", sensorId),
        where("dataType", "==", "data"),
        where("createdAt", ">=", start),
        where("createdAt", "<", end)
      );
    } else {
      q = query(collection(db, ENV, VERSION, "facilities", facilityId, "sensorHistory"),
        orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
        where("deviceId", "==", sensorId),
        limit(100),
        where("dataType", "==", "data")
      );
    }
    getDocs(q)
      .then((querysnapshot) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setHistory(
          querysnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id };
          })
        );
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        alert("!!!");
        setLoading(false);
        console.error(e);
      });
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    getDataMonth()
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dayjs.locale(language);
  }, [language]);
  return (
    <>
      <Stack
        spacing={1}
        direction="row"
        justifyContent="flex-end"
        alignItems="center"
      >
        <Button variant="outlined" onClick={resetDate}>
          {BasicLanguage.sensor.recent[language]}
        </Button>
        <LocalizationProvider
          dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}
          adapterLocale={language}
        >
          <DatePicker
            disableFuture={true}
            value={date}
            onChange={changeDate}
            format={BasicLanguage.common.date.datePicker.long[language]}
          />
        </LocalizationProvider>
      </Stack>

      <TableContainer
        sx={{
          mt: 2,
          maxHeight: "400px",
          "& .MuiTableCell-head": {
            backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            fontWeight: "bold",
          },
        }}
      >
        <Table stickyHeader>
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>{BasicLanguage.sensor.value[language]}</TableCell>
              <TableCell>{BasicLanguage.sensor.date[language]}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {loading ? (
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell colSpan={2}>
                  <Box
                    sx={{
                      display: "flex",
                      height: 200,
                      justifyContent: "center",
                      alignItems: "center",
                    }}
                  >
                    <CircularProgress />
                  </Box>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            ) : (

              //history table showing list of sensors in relation to the date selected
              displayHistory.map((x) => {
                return (
                  <TableRow key={x.id}>
                    <TableCell>{x.value}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      {moment(x.createdAt.seconds * 1000).format(
                        "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })
            )}
            { }
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>

      <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="space-between" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>

        <Box >
          {history.length > 0 ? (

            <Button onClick={download} variant="outlined" size="medium" sx={{ mr: '2rem', height: "full", width: "full" }}  >
              {BasicLanguage.common.download[language]}
            </Button>

          ) : (
            <></>
          )}

          <FormControlLabel
            control={
              <Checkbox

                checked={zeroFilter}
                onChange={(e) => setZeroFilter(e.target.checked)}
              />
            }
            label={BasicLanguage.sensor.zero[language]}
          />
        </Box>


        <Box>
          <LocalizationProvider
            dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}
            adapterLocale={language}
          >


//for month and year selection
            <DatePicker
              disableFuture={true}
              onChange={(newValue) => {
                if (newValue instanceof Date) {
                  const selectedMonth = newValue.getMonth();
                  changeMonth(selectedMonth); // Pass the selected month to the getData function
                } else {
                  console.error("Invalid date format:", newValue);
                }
              }}
              sx={{ padding: "0px", outline: "none" }}
              label={BasicLanguage.users.activityReport.date.format[language]}
              value={month} // Use the month state as the value
              views={['month', 'year']} />
          </LocalizationProvider>
        </Box>
      </Stack >

    </>
  );
};
```

I made changes in the query in order to fetch the data based on month, however I have an error that seems to be a problem of date format and I dont know what to do. I searched a lot on google if there was any example to fetch the data based off on month and year but was not able to find any.

Comment: Hello Welcome to SO. Please read about creating [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you provide so much code which is irrelevant with your exact issue, it becomes really difficult to focus on that specific issue.